# How to make mat-slide-toggle with confirm

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5, slidetoggle

The problem that I have in my code below is, when I click on the **confirm**, the switch changes. I want the switch to change only when I click OK.

Can you suggest me any idea? How to make mat-slide-toggle with confirm?

Html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="myform" class="col s12">
<div *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp;let i = index">
            <section class="example-section">
            <mat-slide-toggle value="active" formControlName="active-{{i}}" class="example-margin" [checked]="item.active === '1'"(click)="onActiveHomeboxP()"> {{item.active}}
            </mat-slide-toggle>
        </section>
</div>
</form>
```

ts code:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public homeboxsp: HomeboxP[] = [];
  myform: FormGroup;
  checkedBtn: boolean;
  constructor(public service: Service) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.populateFormHomeboxP();
  }
  populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.homeboxsp = this.service.getData();


    let controls = {
      'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    };

    for (let i = 0; i < this.homeboxsp.length; i++) {
      controls['active-' + i] = new FormControl(this.homeboxsp[i].active == '1', Validators.required)
    }
    this.myform = new FormGroup(controls);
    this.patchForm();
  }
  patchForm() {
    this.myform.patchValue({
      homeboxpackage_id: this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.homeboxpackage_id),
    });
    console.log(this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.active))
    console.log(this.homeboxsp.map(x => x.homeboxpackage_id))
  }
  onActiveHomeboxP() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      let edigps = this.myform.value
      console.log(edigps)
      console.log('true')
    } else {
      this.checkedBtn = !this.checkedBtn;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can do a stackblitz with your code, it would be useful to help you

Comment: This is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmznlu?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Kalamarico I add in comment link. Can you suggest me any idea please?

Comment: Ok, let me see when I have time, I will check in this morning

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm waiting

Comment: @Kalamarico Please, can you look stackblitz code? Thnx again

Comment: Yes sorry, yesterday was a crazy day, give me some minutes. the answer you have it's not useful?

Comment: @Kalamarico no, it's not works for me

Comment: Ok, it's not finish, take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2x6wf8 first you need to use the (change) event not the click. (change) is fired when slide changes, so, show the confirm and if it false, set the checked as the previous state (when change fires, the checked value is changed yet, but not showed for the moment in the ui) but there still a problem with the 'cancel' button, if you cancel for 2 times it's not working fine. I have no time now, when I will have in this day I back again, but you can check for the moment

Answer (score 3):

If you have an object you can reassign the value after the (change) event:

```
<mat-slide-toggle (change)="slideToggleChange($event, obj)">
   Change me
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

```
slideToggleChange(event: MatSlideToggleChange, obj: any): void {
    event.source.checked = obj.enabled; // Force slide toggle with our value
  
    // Open confirmation dialog
    this.dialog.open(ConfirmationDialog, {
        data: config,
    }).afterClosed().subscribe(
        (confirm: boolean) => {
        if (confirm === true) {
            // Do something
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is a sample one for multiple switch, You can add your extra logics :

HTML

```
<section class="example-section">
  <div *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp;let i = index">
    <mat-slide-toggle class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checkedBtn[i]" (click)="onActiveHomeboxP(i)">
    </mat-slide-toggle>
  </div>
</section>
```

TS

```
  checkedBtn: any[]=[];
  homeboxsp = ['a','b','c'];

  constructor() {    
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onActiveHomeboxP(i:any) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {

      console.log('true')
    } else {
      this.checkedBtn[i] = !this.checkedBtn[i];
    }


  }
```

Comment: If you're using types, try to avoid using `any`. In this case, the argument for `onActiveHomeboxP` should be typed `number`

Answer (score 0):

```
demo (e , element){ 
console.log(element.status);
if (element.status == true){
    if(confirm('true button deactive Are you sure')){
        this.getUsersService.changeStatus(element.id).subscribe((data) => {
            if (data === 'error') {
                e.source.checked = true;                    
                this.snackBar.open('Server Error happened please try later.', '', {
                    duration: 3000,
                    panelClass: ['error-snackbar']
                });
                
            } else {
                e.source.checked = false;
                this.callSkipLevelUsers();
```

**Reload table**

```
                    this.snackBar.open('user status changed succesfully!!!', '', {
                        duration: 3000,
                        panelClass: ['success-snackbar']
                    });
                   
                }
            });
        } else {
            e.source.checked = true;
        }
    } else {
        if(confirm('false button active Are you sure')){
            this.getUsersService.changeStatus(element.id).subscribe((data) => {
                if (data === 'error') {
                    e.source.checked = false;
                    this.snackBar.open('Server Error happened please try later.', '', {
                        duration: 3000,
                        panelClass: ['error-snackbar']
                    });
                    
                } else {
                    e.source.checked = true;
                    this.callSkipLevelUsers();
    reload table 
                    this.snackBar.open('user status changed succesfully!!!', '', {
                        duration: 3000,
                        panelClass: ['success-snackbar']
                    });
                   
                }
            });
        } else {
            e.source.checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Angular mat table mat slider work for me**